# How to enable jpeg suppot for php GD in aws linux 2?

Tags: php, amazon-linux-2

I am using php7.4 also installed php-gd using yum install php-gd and also restart my httpd service and also reboot my server.

installed libjpeg but still getting

```
Array (
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] =>
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] =>
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] =>
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] =>
    [BMP Support] => 1
    [TGA Read Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```